# i can't get file from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to archive the photos that I request to insert from a form using vue, which then interfaces with a firestore repository to save the image and with a firebase db for the rest of the data, on the db I also save the path created by getDonwloadPath . Despite this I still can't see the images.
[save to firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjL1e.png),(https://i.stack.imgur.com/THVfW.png)
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qziq2.png)
[get image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAMIJ.png)

```
<q-table
      style="height: 400px"
      flat
      bordered
      grid
      grid-header
      card-container-class="q-pa-md row justify-center table_card "
      title="Negozzio"
      :columns="columns"
      :rows="filteredRows"
      row-key="id"
      virtual-scroll
      v-model:pagination="pagination"
      :rows-per-page-options="[4]"
    >
      <template v-slot:item="props">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 table_card">
          <q-card flat bordered>
            <img :src="props.row.image" width="100px" height="200px" />

            <q-card-section>
              <div class="text-overline text-orange-9">
                {{ props.row.overline }}
              </div>
              <div class="text-h5 q-mt-sm q-mb-xs">{{ props.row.name }}</div>
              <q-separator />
              <div class="text-caption text-grey">
                {{ props.row.description }}
              </div>
            </q-card-section>

            <q-card-actions>
              <q-btn
                flat
                color="primary"
                label="Add to cart"
                @click="addToCart(props.row)"
              />
              <q-btn flat color="secondary" @click="addFavorite(props.row)" label="favorite" :class="{ 'is-favorite': isFavorite }"/>
              <q-space />

const rows = ref([]);

try {
  $q.loading.show({ message: "Loading ..." });
  (async () => {
    rows.value = await getAll("productsList")
  })();
  console.log(rows.value );
  $q.loading.hide();
} catch (e) {
  triggerNegative($q.notify, e?.message);
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbqTt.png)

Get widget with foto, name, description, uid ecc

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: I will also point out that one of your code samples "save to firestore" doesn't work with Firestore at all.  It's working with Realtime Database, which is a completely different database product.